# C# Console Application fails reading files on restart

Tags: c#, console, restart

Its hard to place everything in the title, but I hope I can explain this as good as I can. Basicly I made a C# Console Application that reads a certain file every now and then. The Application runs on a Virtual Machine from Google Instances. Now I have created another Console Application that is capable of managing the other application, like closing them or restarting the executables.

The Issue:
When I start the Console Application by hand (manual), it works fine and reads the files like it should. I could close and open this as much as I like and it still works. The problem is when my second Console Application tries to restart the first Console Application. The restart works fine and most functions like certain ftp connections work, but it stops reading files and gives a null back as result. There happen to be no debug errors nor does it display an error on the console.

What I want is that the second application could restart my first application without making it run where some functions appear to be blocked.

The Code I use:

```
            string loc = File.ReadAllText(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\"+ "location.txt");
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = loc;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            p.Start();
```

I tried running it as `p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";` but this has no positive result either. Could this be an issue with the Google Virtual Machine, possible firewall settings or code related issues.

**Extra**
This code does work on my own laptop and so does it work after restarting.

Comment: this code reads an executable's file name from a file with "exe" extension. Are you sure this is what you intended?

Comment: How does your second "console application" run?  Is it being run from an interactive shell from a normal login, or is being run from a scheduled job, from a service, or something like that.  "Service-y" applications see a different view of the world (a user's profile may not be loaded, permissions may be different, etc.)

Comment: I agree with @dlatikay why are you trying to read text from an executable? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: Try setting the  `WorkingDirectory` on `ProcessStartInfo`.

Comment: @Flydog57 I edited the code, sorry for the mis conception